# Using multiple instances of Vuetify on the same page

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Long story short I have a website that has been slowly migrating towards Vue. There are many small independent widgets that are each their own Vue app on the same page.

We have a need to add Vuetify to several of these widgets. For example the navbar which is it's own Vue app and then the footer which is also it's own Vue app. The architecture of the application does not allow us to combine these into one app (yet).

Adding Vuetify to more than one instance breaks the other instances when you wrap a second app with the [**`<v-app>`**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/) tag because, as the docs say:

> Vuetify doesn’t support multiple isolated Vuetify instances on a page. v-app can exist anywhere inside the body of your app, however, there should only be one and it must be the parent of ALL Vuetify components.

The `<v-app>` tag adds a `data-app="true"` attribute so I have tried adding this to the `<body>` tag of the application by hardcoding like this:

```
<body data-app="true">
```

But that does not seem to register Vuetify properly.

Since the main application does not use Vue at the root level, how can I wrap all of these apps with a single `<v-app>` and get Vuetify to work for multiple instances?

***Update** per the comment thread below*

The way the apps are setup is like this:

```
...
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify';
import NavbarApp from '@/apps/navbar/NavbarApp.vue';
import OtherWidgetApp from '@/apps/navbar/OtherWidgetApp.vue';

const navbarAppRootEl = document.getElementById('navbarApp');
const NavbarAppRoot = Vue.extend(NavbarApp);

new NavbarAppRoot({
  el: navbarAppRootEl,
  store,
  router,
  vuetify,
  propsData: {
    lang: config.lang,
  },
  i18n,
});

const otherWidgetRootEl = document.getElementById('navbarApp');
const OtherWidgetRoot = Vue.extend(OtherWidgetApp);

new OtherWidgetRoot({
  el: otherWidgetRootEl,
  store,
  router,
  vuetify,
  propsData: {
    lang: config.lang,
  },
  i18n,
});
```

Other apps are setup using that same pattern above, this is an example with two of the apps.

Comment: from the doc I would say there should only be one v-app within your app. but if you embed 2 apps on one page it still should not be a problem. since vue application has a single entry point to start the app within a container and then within this container the vuetify plugin searches for v-app.
did you try it and run into errors? if yes you should explain exactly how you embed+start the 2 apps and what's the error you are getting.

Comment: @oshell I have added the additional information around how the apps are setup.

Comment: and having v-app in each app results in an error?

Comment: @oshell yes. Once I have more than one on the same page the other apps break entirely and do not show - though I do not get any devtool errors.

Comment: okay so if your page is not a vue application itself, but you only run vue on certain parts of your page, I guess it's quite difficult to fix. as their doc states they expect your page to have a single v-app instance within the vue app of your page, which contains ALL vuetify components. you won't be able to fix it by setting v-app somewhere above. you basically have to make the whole page one vue app. it's a strange limitation they have, but they probably have their reasons.